# C#, Best way to loop through NHibernate objects without loading entire set into memory

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, out-of-memory

I'm trying to loop through a large table and write the entries to a csv file.  If I load all Objects into memory I get an *OutOfMemoryException*. My `Employer` class is mapped with fluent *nhibernate*.

Here's what I've tried:

This Loads all object on first iteration and crashes.

```
var myQuerable = DataProvider.GetEmployer();  // returns IQuerably
foreach (var emp in myQuerable)
{
    //  stuff...
}
```

No luck here:

```
var myEnumerator = myQuerable.GetEnumerator();
```

I thought this would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myQuerable.Count(); i++)
{
    Employer e = myQuerable.ElementAt(i);
}
```

but am getting this exception:

> Could not parse expression
>   'value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[MyProject.Model.Employer]).ElementAt(0)':
>   This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.ElementAt' is currently not supported

Am I missing something here?  Is this even possible with *nHibernate*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I'm going to have to follow this artical:

http://ayende.com/blog/4548/nhibernate-streaming-large-result-sets

or use straight ado for performance.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think loading your entries one by one could resolve your problem fully, as this is gonna go to another bad direction - huge loading on database side and longer response time for your C# method. I can't imagine how long it will take, as you've already god OutOfMemoryException exception that indicate you have huge number of records. I think the mechanism you really should take is pagination. There're various materials on the Internet about this topic, such as [NHibernate 3 paging and determining the total number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761197/nhibernate-3-paging-and-determining-the-total-number-of-rows).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In doing some more research I came across this artical.  http://ayende.com/blog/4548/nhibernate-streaming-large-result-sets   it looks promising...

Comment: Admittedly, the way in the article you mentioned is tidier and better.